# Error: A <Router> may have only one child element. Contains Switch, Worked before with this code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Issue:
I am having some trouble with React Router. I receive the error  "A  may have only one child element."

My current setup is such that my Navbar container and the switch are both children of the router. This was working before and I have it working like this on an other project so I'm not sure what I broke.

What I have tried: 
I have tried to wrap it all the switch tag (so the nav container and all routes are in there) which will compile but then I get a warning "React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element." and it does not display the routes as it did previously when it was working.

I have tried to exclude the nav container from the router and move the  tag to right above the  with the routes but I receive an error that states "Link-to must be used inside of a "

Any advice? thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "shards-ui/dist/css/shards.min.css"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faBookOpen, faTags, faHistory, faShoppingBag, faUserCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Container, Row, Col } from "shards-react";
import Main from "../pages/Main/Main.js"
import Deals from "../pages/Deals/Deals.js"
import Menu from "../pages/Menu/Menu.js"
import Cart from "../pages/Cart/Cart.js"
import Previous from "../pages/Previous/Previous.js"
import Profile from "../pages/Profile/Profile.js"

import "../Nav/Navbar.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";


export default class NavContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>

      <Container className="nav-menu-container">


        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Link to="/deals">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTags}/>
              <h6>Deals</h6>
           </Link>
          </Col>
           <Col>
             <Link to="/menu">
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookOpen}/>
               <h6>Menu</h6>
             </Link>
           </Col>
           <Col>
             <Link to="/cart">
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingBag}/>
               <h6>Cart</h6>
             </Link>
           </Col>
           <Col>
             <Link to="/previous">
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHistory}/>
               <h6>Previous</h6>
            </Link>
          </Col>
          <Col>
             <Link to="/profile">
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle}/>
               <h6>Profile</h6>
             </Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
   </Container>

   <Switch>


          <Route path="/deals">
            <Deals />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/menu">
            <Menu />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/cart">
            <Cart />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/previous">
            <Previous />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/profile">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Main />
          </Route>




        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping `Container` and `Switch` with a `React.Fragment`?

```
<Router>
  <React.Fragment>
    <Container>
      ...
    </Container>
    <Switch>
      ...
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that out and did make the  "<Router> may have only one child element" error but caused it to lose functionality with no returned errors. I have since returned to an older version before I had installed some dependencies and was able to get it to work with the code as is but I'm still not 100% sure that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Try interchanging your routes(Move main on top) inside switch and add **exact** props to your main.

```
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/">
   <Main />
 </Route>

 ... other routes here

</Switch
```

Also for a more cleaner look. You could change your Route into this:

From:

```
<Route path="/deals">
  <Deals />
</Route>
```

To:

```
<Route path="/deals" component={Deals} />
```

READ MORE HERE: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I tried this and it did not change the error but thank you for the tips on cleaning up the code! I'm thinking now the issue may be related to a dependency I have installed because I went back to an older version and was able to get it to work as is. I implemented your suggestion for the route path and appreciate the resource too.